# Algorithm for finding file size of all subfolder for a directory structure

Tags: java, tree, traversal

I have a folder structure with ROOT as the parent of all folders. There are n number of folders at level 1 and each of those folders have files and max. n children folders which in turn can have files and directories of their own. The maximum depth of the tree is unknown.

I need to find the directory size for each dir at each level which is the sum of immediate file sizes + sub-directory size.

I've been trying to use depth first and breadth first algorithm to traverse the tree.

Is there a more optimized way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Unless the size data is already stored as metadata with the directory, no, you will need to access each file to determine the size, so you will have to access all n nodes anyhow.

Comment: In what way is that sub-optimal?  Presumably you visit each entry no more than once?